# Good Multi-media music player with video game music playback

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, music, music-player

I have recently switched from Windows 10 to Linux and I am very happy with the performance and customization. There is only 1 thing that I miss from Windows 10 and that is my Music. I cannot listen to my apple music (because iTunes doesn't run on wine) which I can do without, but I have a lot of video game music that I listen to in emulator/tracker format. I used to use winamp for this in Windows but running winamp through wine is a CPU hog (which is understandable seeing how it is translating lots of stuff).

I tried out some alternatives for linux such as deadbeef and audacious. By far Audacious was the best sounding, it had VGM, and SPC support but not n64 USF format support (not a lot of programs support n64 formats to be fair). The VGM playback was fine but the SPC playback was terrible. I have included a link to a winamp vs. audacious comparison and you will see what I mean. [Comparison](https://www.mediafire.com/file/jyzksg8gv04sae3/Comparison.tar.7z/file)

In short, wine will not work because it takes up my CPU while im trying to play games, and I can't find a multi-format videogame/normal music player that has good SPC playback. Does anyone know how I can get good SPC playback without having to convert it to an ogg? (It would take up gigabytes if I converted them to ogg)

EDIT:
Would also like to mention that I did try to mess with the settings to get audacious to sound better but whatever I did made little difference. I did things such as enabling resampling (44100 Hz) and switching to alsa and going strait to hardware.

Comment: Audacious does play USF. You need this one https://github.com/saschaklick/audacious-usf-plugin

Comment: Unfortunately audacious-usf-plugin from the above repo doesn't work correctly with Audacious 4+. Playing a single file works, but Audacious stops working when trying to change to another track or closing the player. According to gdb, a SIGSEGV is thrown. I'd fix it myself, if I knew jack about coding in C. The problem isn't restricted to Ubuntu, same issue with Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Programs that run natively in Linux:

1. ZXTune : https://zxtune.bitbucket.io/
2. DeaDBeeF : https://deadbeef.sourceforge.io/
3. Audacious : https://audacious-media-player.org/
4. VLC : https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.zh_TW.html, though its functionality is a bit limited in some cases, it does not support subsongs playback on .nsf

Foobar2000 along with Game Emu Player and other plugins work problem-free on Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes standard with a few tools for audio and video. I use those defaults on systems that I don't spend a lot of time on. Depending on the Ubuntu version, those apps might change over time.
On my main computers I just keep going back to VLC just because I like that everything is the same no matter what computer I'm at, and the software does a great job and has an abundance of features for both audio and video...and it's light-weight.

It doesn't matter what computer you're on (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, ...), VLC works everywhere. It supports nearly any format and there are a wide variety of plugins and visualizations should you ever need them.

`sudo apt install vlc`

Coming from Winamp, you shouldn't have too much trouble adjusting to the new interface.

There are of course a wide range of media players and it all boils down to preference. Just google "media players ubuntu" and you'll get a long list to choose from.